# Getting wrong array size in picturebox to byte array function

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, picturebox

When trying to convert a picturebox to a byte array, I get a wrong array length

The PictureBox is 352 * 288 = 101376 pixels, converting to a byte array should give an array length of 101376 * 3 = 304128 bytes. I try to convert to an array using the following function:

```
  private byte[] ImgToByteArray(Image img)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
    }
```

I call the function like so:

```
 Byte[] LogImg = ImgToByteArray(LogPictureBox.Image);
 Int LogSize = LogImg.Length
```

The returned value of LogSize = 1070. I find this weird, it should be 304128.

I don't understand it by using breakpoints, I validated the LogPictureBox.Image size to be 352 * 288. So what am I doing wrong here?

I also tried a function with memory stream method method to copy image to array like below, but is also resulted in a wrong size

```
Public Function ImgToByteArray(ByVal img As Image) As Byte()
    Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
        img.Save(mStream, img.RawFormat)
        Return mStream.ToArray()
    End Using
End Function
// called this like
Byte[] LogImg=imgToByteArray((Bitmap)LogPictureBox.Image);
```

As people suggested color depth might be the issue, I coded LogPictureBox to be 24bits p pixel Which equals RGB, still isn't working. Also worth mentioning is that a correct array size (304128) can be retrieved by:

```
Bitmap logBmp = (Bitmap)LogPictureBox.Image;
int logBmpW = logBmp.Width;
int logBmpH = logBmp.Height;
var lockedLog = logBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, logBmpW, logBmpH), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
var logData = new int[lockedLog.Height * System.Math.Abs(lockedLog.Stride)];
// typical marshal code following bitmap to array etc still halted the code
```

I've been hoping that the first 2 functions would work, for the image manipulation I want to do. As I need to update the bitmap array. I've been trying other methods too, (just above here is part of that) but it didn't work either. Then I get into threading issues it seems. Maybe that's a problem with earlier two functions too.

I've got a webcam triggering a newframe event, (Aforge version 2.2.4)  and its this event that's not only updating its own picturebox, but it also needs to set another logging picturebox, apparently threads cause issues here.

Comment: Have you taken a look at what the 1070 bytes look like.  After reading the docs on MSDN my guess is its some kind of string.  Reading that string might shed light on the issue.

Comment: Also, `ImageConverter` is the wrong Class.  To convert an image to a byte array you should use `Image.Save`.

Comment: Image.Save isnt a method of pictureBox

Comment: updated my question with the other function i tried

Comment: Of course not.  `Image` is a property and `Save` is a method of `Image`.

Comment: So thats why i could not do that in the first function, in the second function (update my question) i do use image.Save, but its not working either

Comment: Well, think about what the `Save` method is doing.  I'm sure you'll figure it out.  Also, MSDN is your very best friend.

Comment: What `ImageFormat` are you using?

Comment: I'm using  Format24bppRgb

Comment: _The PictureBox is 352 * 288_ Now if the `Image.Size` is that then it is; but the `PictureBox.Size` is off by the `Border.Width x 2`; always use `PictureBox.ClientSize` !

Comment: But I dont use directly image.size in the above sample for the array length.
??

Comment: Right, I just wanted to point out the misleading terminology. See my updated and simplified answer!

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Well the problem has been resolved, it was caused earlier by some multi threading issues and data that wasnt available at the right moment.  plus wanted to access parts that could not be accessed yet. And this resulted in 'broken' images. I've rewrote my program. And the problem is solved. To many threads can make programming difficult ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The accurate value of bytes/pixel can not compute like that.**

It depends on color depth. A pixel could be represented by just a bit. 
For a 256 color image, a byte per pixel is needed. Additional depth requires more storage, high-color uses 32 bits/4 bytes per pixel.

I test several [Image size in 352x288](http://goo.gl/U9JfVe) and return different value with your code.
You can use another image with same size to test what I said, please try.

**Edit:**
Maybe you can try in different format by this code, then check the length, different filetype will also have different consequence:

```
 public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: 352*288*32 isnt 1070 either ??

Comment: I didn't mean that one pixel is equal to 32 bytes, it depends on your picture.

Comment: I think you need to try another picture also 355*288 pixel and you will understand.

Comment: I know color depth, its just 1070 doesnt match with a known color depth to me. However i will test with different color formats.

Answer (score 0):

The code you tried is not counting the pixels, no matter their depth; it gives the size of the image in its genuine format, including **compression**, including **headers**. So it is very useful to determine the space you need in a `DBMS` or on disk

If you want to calculate the pixel size you need three numbers: `Height, Stride` and `bpp`:

```
int bpp = LogPictureBox.Image.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb ? 3 : 4;
int Stride = (LogPictureBox.Image.Width + 
             (LogPictureBox.Image.Width % (4 * (4 - (bpp / 8))) )) * bpp;
int LogSize = Stride * LogPictureBox.Image.Height;
```

Note that the `bpp` code is very much **incomplete** and assumes either `24` or `32` bit depths!

`Stride` is the physical width, including necessary padding.

Comment: I dont use it in that way, but in other tests i've done today i used 
var logData = new int[lockedLog.Height * System.Math.Abs(lockedLog.Stride)]; // gives correct size
(abs since negative is used in case of bottem to top image data storage). However that code didnt work out, because of threading issues. 
I'm still wondering about coding alternatives.

Comment: "What is lockedLog? The BitmapData from my original answer? See the update!

Comment: sorry updated main problem, after i answered you, because multiple people fell over the bitmapdepth. At first i wasnt approaching it from that direction angle but, since i'm testing, i did include it in my tests